# App in background w/ setTimeout and push notification

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, settimeout, expo

We're running into an issue where Push Notification code is being executed before the setTimeout handler is executed when the app is coming into the foreground.  Here is the sequence of events:

1. User launches the app.  `setTimeout(this.logout, 10000)` gets called.
2. App is put into the background.  Timer continues to count down.
3. Wait for 10 seconds to pass.  Because the app is in the background, `this.logout` callback will not be invoked until the app is bought back into the foreground.
4. Push notification is sent to device.
5. Now, user taps on the Push Notification, which opens the app.
6. Push Notification code is executed
7. `this.logout` code is executed immediately.

The result is that the user is kicked out of the app before he can view the Push Notification.

Is there a way to somehow re-arrange the events in the Event Queue so that this.logout is executed first and Push Notification handling code executed second?

Edit: We're using the Expo Push Notifications SDK

Sample Code

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.notifications = Notifications.addListener(this.handleNotification);
  this.timeout = setTimeout(this.logout, 10000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Notifications.remove(this.notifications);
}

this.handleNotification = () => { ... }
this.logout = () => { ... }
```

Comment: which push notification library are you using, can you also post some snippet of code as well for better understanding.

Comment: @Anrdoid Noob so...if I'm not mistaken, a `callback` function would work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by turning off the setTimeout timer and using timestamps (Date.now() - startTime) to find the amount of time elapsed.